# Google Maps Module custom markers and routeplanner

Tags: google-maps

On my Drupal site, I have a nice Google maps module with custom markers.

The only thing I want to add is a route planner that makes use of my custom
Markers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for module, and should be posted in it's issue queue. If you plan to write this feature yourself, please read [this question on meta](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2561/16495), and it's answers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried https://drupal.org/project/routeplanner ? It's a very simple and lightweight Module to create a route from any address to a fixed point of interest.

Comment: Dear Twinkel, Thank you for your reply. Yes i've tried the routeplanner module indeed. Unfortunaly i haven't been able to get it to work.. But not all is lost. I will try again on a "dummie website" where i can fool around without anny permanent changes. Thanks again for your reply. Greets Michel